# XMLHttpRequest undefined on open

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to print out all the public holidays in the date range and region that are filled out in the form when the submit button is pressed.

I was able to get it working using prompts to collect the input but I want to use a form instead.

**html**

```html
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    Start Date: <input type="text" name="fromDate" id="fromDate" value="04-07-2019"><br>
    End Date: <input type="text" name="toDate" id="toDate" value="04-07-2020"><br>
    Class Country: <input type="text" name="country" id="country" value="usa"><br>
    Region: <input type="text" name="region" id="region" value="dc"><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="Submit">
```

**javascript**

```js
    function submit(){
        var fromDate = document.getElementById("fromDate").name + "=" + document.getElementById("fromDate").value + "&";
        var toDate = document.getElementById("toDate").name + "=" + document.getElementById("toDate").value + "&";
        var country = document.getElementById("country").name + "=" + document.getElementById("country").value + "&";
        var region = document.getElementById("region").name + "=" + document.getElementById("region").value + "&";

        fullURL = "https://kayaposoft.com/enrico/json/v2.0/?action=getHolidaysForDateRange&" + fromDate + toDate + country + region + "holidayType=public_holiday";
        requestUrl()
    }

    function requestUrl(){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

        request.open('GET', fullURL, true)

        request.onload = function () {
            console.log(this.response)
            var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
            data.forEach(holiday => {
                var date = String(holiday.date["day"] + "/" + holiday.date["month"] + "/" + holiday.date["year"])
                document.write(date)

            })
            display()
        }
    }

    function display(){
        request.send()
    }
```

I'm getting this error :

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0" at JSON.parse, requestURL, submit and HTMLInputElement.onclick.
```

Comment: The error is about the JSON text that your code attempts to parse. What exactly does the response text look like?

Comment: compare the url that works vs the one that has the issue. What is different?

Comment: It should look like `[{"date":{"day":4,"month":7,"year":2019,"dayOfWeek":4},"name":[{"lang":"en","text":"Independence Day"}],"holidayType":"public_holiday"}]`` but it's coming up as undefined. If I print the url it generates in the console, it shows json, like I'd expect.

Comment: How does it even run with display() inside of the onload callback and the send() is inside display?

Comment: You should check what the Network tab in your browser console shows you about the response. If you're trying to fetch from another domain, that target domain must be explicitly configured to allow it. If it isn't, your request will fail with a CORS error.

Comment: I just ran it. I moved the send() into the right block and it worked so.....

Comment: @epascarello by *“I moved the send() into the right block and it worked”*, do you mean the problem is now resolved?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I'm not the OP

Comment: @epascarello oops sorry yeah I should have read more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
        const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
        btn.addEventListener("click",submit)
        function submit(){
            var fromDate = document.getElementById("fromDate").name + "=" + document.getElementById("fromDate").value + "&";
            var toDate = document.getElementById("toDate").name + "=" + document.getElementById("toDate").value + "&";
            var country = document.getElementById("country").name + "=" + document.getElementById("country").value + "&";
            var region = document.getElementById("region").name + "=" + document.getElementById("region").value + "&";

            fullURL = "https://kayaposoft.com/enrico/json/v2.0/?action=getHolidaysForDateRange&" + fromDate + toDate + country + region + "holidayType=public_holiday";
            requestUrl()
        }

        function requestUrl(){
            // 1. Create a new XMLHttpRequest object
            let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // 2. Configure it: GET-request for the URL /article/.../load
            request.open('GET', fullURL);

            // 3. Send the request over the network
            request.send();

            // 4. This will be called after the response is received
            request.onload = function() {
                if (request.status != 200) { // analyze HTTP status of the response
                    alert(`Error ${request.status}: ${request.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found

                } else { // show the result
                    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    data.forEach(holiday => {
                        var date = String(holiday.date["day"] + "/" + holiday.date["month"] + "/" + holiday.date["year"])
                        document.write(date)

                    })
                }
            };
        }
```

```html
    <div id="root"></div>


    <div>
        Start Date: <input type="text" name="fromDate" id="fromDate" value="04-07-2019"/><br>
        End Date: <input type="text" name="toDate" id="toDate" value="04-07-2020"/><br>
        Class Country: <input type="text" name="country" id="country" value="usa"/><br>
        Region: <input type="text" name="region" id="region" value="dc"/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try that yourself?

Comment: well you copied issues over with display() so you have an error when it runs.

Comment: My fault! fixed.